# Strings should have translatable content. How to fix?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpcs

I tried to find similar topics, but the proposed solutions did not help me.

```
$posted_on = sprintf(
    /* translators: %s: post date. */
    esc_html_x( '%s', 'post date', 'mytheme' ), ' ' . $time_string . '' );
echo '' . $posted_on . '';
```

Result: Strings should have translatable content.
Looks like the validator swears at '%s' in sprintf

Comment: just a comment : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/

Comment: How does this help me?

Comment: it is the documentation on translatable strings.

Comment: like `sprintf( __( 'You can visit the page by clicking <a href="%s">here</a>.', 'text_domain' ), 
            'http://example.com'
        );` would take the translation from your .PO file

Comment: I know that. I can not understand why the validator swears on the variable %s

Comment: I stupid fool. I just need to delete anything, and leave only '%1$s'